# Twilio video call In App Background & Closed on iOS

Tags: ios, twilio, ios10

I had successfully setup the video SDK for video call if app is in foreground but having no idea how to do it when app is in background or closed.

Comment: can you please explain how would you interact with video call when your app is closed or in the background?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS right now we are using push notification to send or recieve audio/video call

Comment: You can use CallKit in iOS 10, check out [this example](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift) to see how.

Comment: @philnash that is already implemented.
Using push notification for call and video call how it can be done when app is closed and in background

Comment: Push notifications should wake the application up, and with callkit, it should wake up as if it were a phone call. If you already have push notifications setup what are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Background Modes inside Capabilities in your target.

Twilio Audio will work when your application enter in background.

[image]

Comment: right now i am using push notification to send or recieve call.

Comment: You need to use VoIP Push Service Certificate , to receive video call when application is terminated .      [Voice Over IP](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html) .                           [Look this example](https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip)